# Adding a language switch to a custom block

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have this in my .info file:

```
regions[lang_switch] = switcher
```

I have set the block to the switcher region.

But having `<?php print $lang_switch ?>` in my page.tpl.php file gives me an error such as this:

Notice: Undefined variable: lang_switch in include() (line 16 of /sites/all/themes/basic/templates/page.tpl.php). =>

I am pretty sure this is all I did last time and it worked, although I did it in d6, I couldn't really get useful info from Drupal's site though...
Thanks in advance! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this one:

```
<?php print render($page['lang_switch']); ?>
```